# Have a wrapper object expose its wrapee's properties

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, wrapper

I'm currently trying to figure out how to have a wrapper class expose the properties of whatever it is wrapping without having to manually set them one by one in the wrapper class. I've been trying to figure out if this is even a good design choice or if I'm totally misguided and going off into a very bad place™ by doing this.

I also already have my wrapper class inheriting something...

Example code below (fake objects so don't read into them please):

```
public class Car {
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Status { get; set; }
    public String Type { get; set; }

    public Car(takes params) {
        // makes car!
    }
}

public class CarWrapper : OtherAutomotiveRelatedThing {
    public Car car;        

    public CarWrapper(Car c) {
        car = c;
    }
}

public class OtherAutomotiveRelatedThing {
    public String Property1 { get; protected set; }
    public String Property2 { get; protected set; }
}
```

I'm using inheritance on the wrapper object because I can not modify the base Car class and it needs the properties of other automotive thing. Multiple other classes inherit from OtherAutomotiveRelatedThing as well.

I return a list of the CarWrapper objects as Json (because I'm building a web app) and the wrapper object is causing problems for me. When cast/converted to Json the CarWrapper objects in the list all contain another nested object - the Car object and the framework I'm using can't get at its properties to do what it needs.

Is there a way to expose the wrapped Car object's properties at the "top level" of the CarWrapper without doing the following:

```
public class CarWrapper : OtherAutomotiveRelatedThing {
    public Car car; 
    public String Name { get; private set; }
    public String Status { get; private set; }
    public String Type { get; private set; }

    public CarWrapper(Car c) {
        car = c;
        this.Name = c.Name;
        this.Status = c.Status;
        this.Type = c.Type;
    }
}
```

Please let me know if I'm not being clear, if you have any questions, or need/want more info.

Thanks!

Comment: are you trying to tackle this issue for your json need, or purely over c#?
the former is not a truly OOP, and it run in different platform compare to c#.

Comment: I want to take care of this problem in C#. The problem I brought up with Json is just a symptom, feel free to ignore that. I feel like I currently have a sub-optimal solution and this issue when serializing it to Json was the first one of many I will see if I don't address the underlying Object model of my code (is that the right way to say - I want to make sure I've coded my classes, inheritance, etc... the right way?)

Comment: Can you make OtherCarRelatedThing inherit from DynamicObject? If so, I can propose a solution using that mechanism.

Comment: Sorry about the delay. Yeah - I can make the OtherCarRelatedThing inherit from anything I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it looks like you want `prototype`-style programming like in JavaScript, which is not they use in OOP.

Maybe it's good start to think of it as "If I have two different car wrappers (with differnt properties set), how should I pass any of them a method?" or "Can I have a single wrapper which wraps Car and Animal", and "How to expose public property which has the same name but different meaning for Car and Animal, like `skin color`?" etc

Answers may help you identify if you need say interfaces, or wrappers which expose public objects, or pure encapsulation, or changing language to say JavaScript.